# How can I step into a second shell script using Bash Debug in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: bash, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Using RHEL 7.9 (kernel 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64) I have a folder under my home directory containing a project:
`/home/myself/project`

This project contains Bash scripts, with one serving as the entry point that invokes some of the other ones.

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.52.0, and I have installed Bash Debug 0.3.9.

I can step through the entry point script at `/home/myself/project/entry.sh`, but when I set a breakpoint in `/home/myself/project/second.sh` (which gets called), it never breaks there.

I know it calls it because I see the output of `second.sh`.

The docs state "Currently debugger stops at first command".

Does this mean what I want to do is impossible with this tool? You can only debug one script at a time?

In addition, some shell scripts end up calling Python, which I also want to debug..

Comment: Ever figure this out?  No problem doing this thing in Python...

Comment: @DannyHolstein IIRC, I had to modify the entry shell script to call the other scripts using source (or . if you prefer). That way it was considered part of the same shell being debugged. Otherwise I could not get it to work.

Comment: As with "source"?

Comment: @DannyHolstein yep. In my case the entry point shell was not really supposed to source in the other scripts, since in that case I think the environment variables are no longer distinct and perhaps some other things behave differently, but it was good enough for debugging and changing back afterwards.